# How to assign value for every keys in dictionary using fromkeys()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
d = {}.fromkeys(range(1,6),"one")
print(d)
```

How can I assign a different value for every key?

To be specific: I want `{1:"One",2:"Two", 3:"three", 4:"four", 5:"five"}` .

Is this possible to do so if I use `fromkeys()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [`.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) is designed to add keys with a single default value.

> Create a new dictionary with keys from seq and values set to value.
>
> `fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value
>   defaults to `None`.

For your use case, you may just need to "zip" and make a dictionary out of pairs:

```
In [1]: dict(zip(range(1, 6), ["One", "Two", "three", "four", "five"]))
Out[1]: {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}
```